# Why does the matlab bootstrap procedure evaluate N+1 times?

Tags: matlab, statistics-bootstrap

I wanted to bootstrap with matlab using the built in command "bootstrp". What I noticed was that the procedure makes N+1 iterations when I am only asking for N iterations. Why is that? When I build a manual loop to do the bootstrapping, so that it really just runs N times, then it is faster. Here is a minimal example of the problem:

```
clear all

global iterationcounter

tic

iterationcounter=0;
data=unifrnd(0,1,1,1000); %draw vector of 1000 random numbers

bootstat = bootstrp(100,@testmean,data); %evaluate function for 100 bootstrap samples
toc
```

which uses the function

```
function [ m ] = testmean( data )
global iterationcounter

m=mean(data);

iterationcounter=iterationcounter+1

end
```

The function should evaluate 100 samples, yet when I run the script, it will evaluate the function 101 times:

> ...
>
> iterationcounter =
>
> 101
>
> Elapsed time is 0.102291 seconds.

So why should one use this build-in Matlab function that appears to waste time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bootstrp` makes a call to `bootfun` (the function argument) for sanity checks (from the source code, in MATLAB 2015b, `bootstrp.m`, l.167 ff) :

```
% Sanity check bootfun call and determine dimension and type of result
try
    % Get result of bootfun on actual data, force to a row.
    bootstat = feval(bootfun,bootargs{:});
    bootstat = bootstat(:)';
catch ME
    m = message('stats:bootstrp:BadBootFun');
    MEboot =  MException(m.Identifier,'%s',getString(m));
    ME = addCause(ME,MEboot);
    rethrow(ME);
end
```

I would think that in a realistic application, `N>>100`, so the extra overhead is (much) less than a percent of he total runtime (not taking into account speed gains from possible parallelisation), so that should not matter that much?

Comment: That explains it, thanks! You are right, as N gets large the difference won't matter as much. Still, it puzzled me and if you are trying to test the code for one or two iterations, then it takes half or a third times as much with this additional run, so you start to notice (one iteration takes something between 1-3 min in my case).